# Detroit's own Eminem -- meaning?

Tags: meaning, expressions

From the movie [*The Interview* (2014)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2788710/):

> Good evening. I'm Dave Skylark. Tonight, we are joined by 13-time Grammy winner, Oscar-winning songwriter, **Detroit's own** Eminem.

How do you understand that type of phrasing? And would you please provide some extra examples as well?

Comment: It means Eminem came from Detroit and it's usually said when the show is being put on *in* Detroit.  So it  means "he's from here; he's a local."

Comment: @Jim you should make your comment an answer so Cookie Monster can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Own* is often used as an emphasiser to enhance or draw attention to the closeness or possessional aspect of the relationship.

Some examples:

- *I'll be staying in my own home tonight*. Draws attention to the fact that it's not anyone else's home. Perhaps I'm returning from holiday or have just purchased my first house, and so am excited to finally be staying there.
- *Vincent van Gogh cut off his own ear*. Cutting off one's own ear is quite unusual. *Own* makes it explicit that *his* refers to *van Gogh*, and not some other man.

In this specific instance, *Detroit's own* calls attention to the fact that Eminem hails from Detroit. However, in the movie, Eminem is performing in New York City<sup>[1](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2788710/synopsis?ref_=ttpl_pl_syn)</sup>. [As mentioned by Jim](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49034/detroits-own-eminem-meaning#comment91465_49034), this phrasing is often used when introducing a performer who is appearing in their hometown, but this need not be the case. *Own* can be used any time you want to add emphasis; for example, to add a bit of verbal flair to one's speech, such as a talk show host may be wont to do.